# Sabre Dev Studio API OTA_HotelAvailRQ - ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR Error

Tags: soap, sabre

I am building a third party my client app and they want to use the Sabre API.

I tried to create a `SessionCreateRQ` and it is working fine and getting session ID as well.

Then I want to get hotel availability in real time. I am getting the following response. Can you please help me to resolve this?

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">

    <SOAP-ENV:Header>

        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">

            <eb:ConversationId>123456</eb:ConversationId>

            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"></eb:PartyId>

            </eb:From>

            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"></eb:PartyId>

            </eb:To>

            <eb:CPAId>DEVCENTER</eb:CPAId>

            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Service>

            <eb:Action>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>

            <eb:MessageData>

                <eb:MessageId>977334236793100610</eb:MessageId>

                <eb:Timestamp>2017-09-16T11:28:14Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <!--<eb:TimeToLive>2003-12-09T11:16:12Z</eb:TimeToLive> -->

                <eb:Timeout>50</eb:Timeout>

            </eb:MessageData>

        </eb:MessageHeader>

        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">

            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
Shared/IDL:IceSess\\/SessMgr:1\\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\\/CRT.LB!-3232019038338488957!587850!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>

        </wsse:Security>

    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>

        <OTA_HotelAvailRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">




        <AvailRequestSegment>


        <GuestCounts Count="2" />
        <HotelSearchCriteria>
            <Criterion>
                <HotelRef HotelCityCode="DFW" />
            </Criterion>
        </HotelSearchCriteria>
        <TimeSpan End="10-24" Start="10-22" />

        </AvailRequestSegment>

</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>

    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<stl:Message>Sending request to the Host failed</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
```

I am not sure what is wrong but i am getting above error. please help me.

Thanks
kishor

Comment: what's url are you using?

Comment: HI Chris

Thank you so much for your reply.

I am using https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com URL for this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this still ocurring? If yes, can you try removing the <eb:Timeout>50</eb:Timeout>?